# Why is the option to add a ContextMenuStrip greyed out in the toolbox in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, contextmenustrip

I've been googling for hours and can't seem to resolve this or add a ContextMenuStrip in via code (as I'm still learning)

Ideally I would like the option to not be greyed in VS2022 as it would make things a lot more simple!

[Toolbox Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpCfC.png)

I have tried resetting the toolbox but this doesn't fix it and I've tried "Choosing Items" but the ContextMenuStrip was already ticked. I've tried unticking and reticking to see if this refreshed it but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of controls are available will actually depend on the kind of project you create.

visual studio is now not only an amazing Swiss Army knife packed with 20 years of features, but also as a result is able to create different kinds of projects of EVERY conceivable type from console applications, phone applications, desktop applications, web-based applications.

Now, you tagged this question with asp.net.

But your screen shot shows you expanded the tree with "All windows forms".

However, creating a web site does not let you use controls for the windows desktop, does it?

Normally if you do not beat the toolbox to death with a frying pan, it should automatic only show controls for the given type of project.

And not only can you create web-based applications, but we have also about 3 or MORE different kinds of web applications. We have for example the older "web forms" choice. That choice gives you a toolbox with drag and drop to a visual designer.

However, if you create a newer "MVC" web site, then you don't have a visual drag and drop designer anymore.

So, if I create a web form asp.net application?
Well, obviously you can't use windows controls in a web browser (which is a VAST different technology and means to display information then controls used for creating desktop applications).

So, with a web forms project, I then see this:

[image]

So, I don't even SEE the "All windows forms" option, since I am NOT using windows forms.

I mean, no chance that windows controls can run and be used in a standard web browser right?

So, Chrome, or Firefox have ZERO clue about some controls that are for Microsoft windows. As a result, you not given "window forms" controls as a choice.

And if you by FORCE ADD the "All windows forms" to a web project, then it will display in the toolbox "tree", but as such they are still disabled/grayed out, since such controls are of no use and cannot be used in web projects.

however, if I create a windows form application, then the toolbox should automatically re-configure, and I see this now

For a windows forms application:

[image]

And I might want to create a desktop application based on WPF (windows presentation foundation). And again, the controls I can use are going to be different then the long-time windows desktop controls.

You HAVE to use WPF controls, and thus the toolbox now shows this:

[image]

So, there are boatloads of different kinds of projects.

And you certainly can't use "windows forms" controls for a web-based application.

so, you did not mention what kind of project you created, but the kind of project you create quite much decides what choice(s) of controls you can use.

You can no more use a windows desktop control on your smartphone, nor can you use such controls in a web browser.

So, "hopefully" then VS will restrict the choices for you.

But, as noted, if you beat up the toolbox, and force display of choices for a project that does not have nor allow such choices?

then the options can be displayed in the toolbox, but they will be disabled.

So, what we REALLY need to know here is what kind of project are you wanting to create, or did create?

That project type choice will then decide and determine what sets of controls you can use for that given type of project.

So, a one-line answer?

the ContextMenuStrip is not a control that you can use nor is it available for a asp.net web project.

Comment: Great answer thank you. The option to see it was only when I showed hidden items. I am trying to add a right click option to a treeview. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, we gone from a menu bar or tab strip to now a right click context menu in a browser? A huge narrative change don't you think? For right click context menus in a browser, you have to adopt client side JavaScript for that to occur. You have to start a new question and show your working tree view markup and code behind for us here to try and answer such a question.  So, yes, a right click context menu is possible in a browser, but you don't see a whole lot of sites using that ability (not touch screen friendly - using a smartphone anyone???).